# Avoid Retrofit ordering list by id

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to get a list from an API. The data I should get is the following:

```
    [{"id":"11028","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-15","time_ini":"05:20:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"11024","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-16","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"10:00:00"},{"id":"11026","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-16","time_ini":"11:00:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"11031","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-16","time_ini":"13:00:00","time_end":"14:00:00"},{"id":"11032","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-16","time_ini":"14:20:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"10975","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-17","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},
{"id":"11030","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-21","time_ini":"05:10:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"10977","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-22","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"10978","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-23","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"10979","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-24","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"10980","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-28","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"10981","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-29","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"10982","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-06-30","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"10983","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-01","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"10984","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-05","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"10985","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-06","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"10986","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-07","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},
{"id":"10987","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-08","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"10988","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-12","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"10989","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-13","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"10990","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-14","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"10991","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-15","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"10992","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-19","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},
{"id":"10993","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-20","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"10994","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-21","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"10995","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-22","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"10996","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-26","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"10997","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-27","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"10998","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-28","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"10999","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-07-29","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"11000","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-02","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"11001","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-03","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},
{"id":"11002","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-04","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"11003","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-05","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"11004","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-09","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"11005","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-10","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"11006","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-11","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"11007","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-12","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"11008","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-16","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"11009","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-17","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"11010","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-18","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},
{"id":"11011","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-19","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"11012","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-23","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"11013","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-24","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"11014","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-25","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"11015","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-26","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"11016","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-30","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},{"id":"11017","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-08-31","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"11018","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-09-01","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"11019","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-09-02","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"},{"id":"11020","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-09-06","time_ini":"04:30:00","time_end":"12:00:00"},
{"id":"11021","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-09-07","time_ini":"05:00:00","time_end":"08:30:00"},{"id":"11022","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-09-08","time_ini":"09:30:00","time_end":"15:30:00"},{"id":"11023","doctor_id":"46","date":"2017-09-09","time_ini":"03:00:00","time_end":"06:00:00"}]
```

And I am geting this using Retrofit:

```
0 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7146} 
 date = "2017-06-16"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "15:30:00"
 timeIni = "14:20:00"
 id = 11032
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1821293683
1 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7147} 
 date = "2017-06-16"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "14:00:00"
 timeIni = "13:00:00"
 id = 11031
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1780684478
2 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7148} 
 date = "2017-06-21"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "12:00:00"
 timeIni = "05:10:00"
 id = 11030
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1993499309
3 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7149} 
 date = "2017-06-15"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "08:30:00"
 timeIni = "05:20:00"
 id = 11028
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1886554480
4 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7150} 
 date = "2017-06-16"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "12:00:00"
 timeIni = "11:00:00"
 id = 11026
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1128559735
5 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7151} 
 date = "2017-06-16"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "10:00:00"
 timeIni = "09:30:00"
 id = 11024
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1252763762
6 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7152} 
 date = "2017-09-09"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "06:00:00"
 timeIni = "03:00:00"
 id = 11023
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1385514065
7 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7153} 
 date = "2017-09-08"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "15:30:00"
 timeIni = "09:30:00"
 id = 11022
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1275368516
8 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7154} 
 date = "2017-09-07"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "08:30:00"
 timeIni = "05:00:00"
 id = 11021
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1941416123
9 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7155} 
 date = "2017-09-06"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "12:00:00"
 timeIni = "04:30:00"
 id = 11020
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1983750502
10 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7156} 
 date = "2017-09-02"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "06:00:00"
 timeIni = "03:00:00"
 id = 11019
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1515101237
11 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7157} 
 date = "2017-09-01"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "15:30:00"
 timeIni = "09:30:00"
 id = 11018
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1829664856
12 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7158} 
 date = "2017-08-31"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "08:30:00"
 timeIni = "05:00:00"
 id = 11017
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1139006783
13 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7159} 
 date = "2017-08-30"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "12:00:00"
 timeIni = "04:30:00"
 id = 11016
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1932015002
14 = {ResponseAppointmentHours@7160} 
 date = "2017-08-26"
 doctorId = 46
 timeEnd = "06:00:00"
 timeIni = "03:00:00"
 id = 11015
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6492} "class com.omnidoctor.omniapp.data.entities.remote.response.ResponseAppointmentHours"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1469025881
```

I am not going to copy all the values to avoid making the post too long but as you can see using retrofit the list is ordered by id. But I need to have it ordered as it comes from the server. How can avoid Retrofit to order the list by id?

Comment: why should retrofit sort your list?

Comment: I am asking the same... I have no idea why it is doing me this.

Comment: AFAIK retrofit won't sort anything for you, the JSON library is used with retrofit is taking care of the serialization. One thing that comes trough my mind is that you might have override ```compareTo``` method and your retrofit method is returning an ordered set. It might help posting the model, retrofit method & maybe JSON configs for retrofit.

Comment: This make the trick! I change compareTo to just return 0 and now it is not reordering by id.